# Video conference module

Tags: 7, files

I have some doubts about the [Video Conference](http://drupal.org/project/vconf) module.

- Can we integrate the video conference module in Drupal 6?
- Can we use [Dokeos](http://www.dokeos.com/en) for video conference?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that module is in the very early stages of development and is not widely deployed.

There is an abandon dokeos module as well, but I think that you may be out of luck with this particular feature?